# Getting Array index on item click

Tags: android, textview

I have created an Android RSS Reader App.I have a text marquee in my android app.Iam fetching RSS feed and store RSS title as an array.Iam setting this array as the marque text.Check the code,

```
String MarqueeStr="";
TextView flashnews;

for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

    MarqueeStr = MarqueeStr +" | "+ Headlines.Title[i];
        }

           flashnews.setText(MarqueeStr);
```

Now I have to set an onclick listener for my marquee, so that user can view detailed description of title which they are clicked.I know how to set it.But my problem is, how can i get the array index of clicked string in the marquee text when a user click on the marquee?

here is my XML layout,

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/flashs"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#e7e7e7" />
```

screen shote here..

[image]

can you see that "Latest News"? its my marquee text

Comment: Can you please provide more details of what you are doing please? Maybe some screenshots or layout files etc

Comment: Can you please add more code. Looks interesting one..!!

Comment: k..check my screen shot here, http://www.4shared.com/photo/ycwenvD-/Capture.html
  can you see that "Latest News"? its a text marque moving horizontally like a flash news.I want to set on click listener for that marquee.when we click on that marque i have to get the index of that selected title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will only be possible if you will create your textviews dynamically and set id for them. like if you are having 10 news link then use 10 textviews

```
        TextView txt = null;
        View.OnClickListener marquee_click = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int selected_item = v.getTag();
                switch (selected_item) {
                case 0:

                    break;
                case 1:

                    break;
                case 2:

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        };


        LinearLayout news_text_layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        news_text_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            txt.setTag(i);   // OR txt.setId(i);
            txt.setText("new " + i);
            txt.setOnClickListener(marquee_click);
            news_text_layout.addView(txt);
        }
        // ADD YOUR LINEAR LAYOUT ON WHICH YOU HAVE ADDED ALL TEXT VIEW IN YOUR LISTVIEW FOOTER.
        // NOW PERFORM SAME ANIMATION OR TRICK ON LINEAR LAYOUT WHICH YOU WERE PERFORMING ON marquee text.
```

Hope it can help you...

Comment: Iam using custom adapter for list view. But I asked about the marquee text.I want to get the index of marquee text.Look at the picture..

Comment: Thanks man, it works! :) i need one more help, how can I perform an autoscroll on Linear layout?

Comment: It should start scrolling horizontally(Like marquee text) when I start the application.And  it should keep scrolling....any idea??

Comment: Actually that textview will be a long one, because it contains a number of strings...so it should autoscroll all the time like a flashnews scrolling bottom of a news channel...

Comment: Iam not talking about listview,I added the text views into a linear layout like you told.It works fine, now i can view the titles in an horizontal linear layout at the bottom of the screen.My problem is, its not moving.we can scroll it using our finger.I need to perform an auto scroll...did u get my qstn?

Comment: check my 1st questn...I provided a layout file...thats the way how i scrolled marquee text

Comment: check that i have answered for animation

Answer (score 1):

You can add every FlashNews as a dynamically created TextView. And you can put all of these in
one HorizontalScrollView. And set their listeners seperatly.

For marquee function, you can programmatically scroll the horizontalView within your code.

I dont know if it's possible to make it with your idea. (Actually it can be done, but it will contain pain i guess)

Answer (score 1):

for animation look at this i have just created.
Create new project then add class and xml file which i am giving.

```
public class Test_stflowActivity extends Activity {
    LinearLayout ll = null;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        final TranslateAnimation ts = new TranslateAnimation(200, -100, 0, 0);
        ll.setAnimation(ts);
        ts.setDuration(5000);
        TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv.setText("*bharat sharma*");
        tv.setTextSize(30);
        ll.addView(tv);
        ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ll.startAnimation(ts);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

it is working for me
```

Comment: Thank you...let me check it out... :)

Comment: What you have to do is first calculate linear layout width and calculate device width and animate your linear layout from device width to its linear layout width.

Comment: I have one doubt, that "float fromXDelta" and "float toXDelta" values are same for all devices? I set float fromXDelta=0 and it works fine on my device..what about the other devices which having a different screen?

Comment: I think it should work for all devices.. because it will allow to move it from beginning of your layout.. I need to check not able to spend lot of time because of office work.. i will check and tell you.. :)

Comment: Hey its ok bro...you have already wasted time for me.And Iam very grateful to you.I will check it myself..thank you :)

Comment: Ok if you check then inform me too :)

Comment: I have replaced your *bharat sharma* string with my array.But Onclick listner is working only for the first text when it animates.Whats the problem?

Comment: I have created multiple text views dynamically  like u showed before.But how can I save those views?

Comment: Can you test one thing dont set animation and try to click on two different text views is it working or not as in my first answer i have set and get tag. if you can debug and check.

Comment: yh..i tested it..and it works perfectly...but when animation comes,problme occurs.

Comment: Something is working or every thing is same... I will try to do it tomorrow at home in office i cant search all those things allot tomorrow till evening I will try to complete.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a `ListView` with an adapter, (which you should), you can use the `getItem(int position)` function to get the specific item.